# How to: find string in GitHub repo?

Tags: git, github, search

I'm searching a fairly major GitHub repo for an error that's a) a big one b) easily fixed. I know where it is from the frontend, I just need to search the entire GitHub repo for a string.

How do I do that?

Comment: Did you try the search bar?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart my Mac doesn't have the search bar: it's an older model

Comment: No, I mean on the GitHub project page.

Comment: I'd probably need a screenshot? I don't use GitHub Project, just the regular site

Comment: That's what I mean. Just go to github.com/whatever. There's a search bar at the top that starts with "This Repository". "GitHub Project" isn't a thing.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart doesn't appear for me: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: What @JonathonReinhart said - have a look at [this link](https://monosnap.com/file/iP3iFv9eZmwHH4QR6QTytdFtcFLL89)

Comment: @DanKreiger I did, it just incorrectly illustrates the idea that if you type a line of code the output will be what you expect; it's naive

Comment: Oh - whenever I need to find a specific string or piece of code in GitHub, I find the search bar to be very reliable. Maybe I misunderstand the problem.

Comment: It perfectly answers the question you've asked. If you have further requirements that aren't met, then why aren't they included in your question?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart the problem is not fixed yet

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd clone the repo (which you'd need to do anyway if you want to create a PR for it) and `git grep` it:

```
$ git grep string_to_look_for
```

Comment: no need for `git [etc] | grep [etc]`, nice, will try

Answer (score 24):

You can search an entire repo in github by using the search bar found at the top left corner of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't search only strings. That searchers everything, including code, comments, and text files.

Comment: You're right. It does filter it for you by categories though.
So after you search you could then click on "code" if you're wanting it to just be code.

Comment: That search bar has never found a single search string in the code, ever. One of Github’s most dysfunctional non-features.

Answer (score 4):

From [GitHub Developer Guide](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code):

```
GET /search/code
```

Example:

https://api.github.com/search/code?q=addClass+in:file+language:js+repo:jquery/jquery

Answer (score 1):

If you are logged in, you can use the search bar at the top left of the page to search within a repository, within the organization, or within all of GitHub. If you are not logged in, the only search bar you will see is in the top right, which always searches all of GitHub.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the .com in the github URL to .dev to open the visual studio code editor in the browser. Then you can use the vscode search function.

E.g., https://github.com/dummy/dummy becomes https://github.dev/dummy/dummy